# Arrays in Ruby: Take vs Limit vs First

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, limit

Suppose you have an array of objects in Rails `@objects`

If I want to display the first 5 objects, what is the difference between using:

1. `@objects.limit(5)`
2. `@objects.take(5)`
3. `@objects.first(5)`

I am talking about the front end (Ruby), **NOT SQL**. The reason why the objects are not limited in SQL is because the same array may be used elsewhere without applying a limit to it.

Does it have anything to do with object instantiation?

Comment: Are you sure @objects is an Array?  I've never heard of a #limit method.  #first however is a standard method to return the first element.  #take is also a method.

Comment: Yes `@objects` is an array. I applied the `#limit` method and it seemed to have performed the same task as `#take` and `#first`. (In the view not the controller).

Comment: @objects is probably not an array but rather an ActiveRecord relation. That is why you use of limit(5) is working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. limit is not an array method
2. take requires an argument; it returns an empty array if the array is empty.
3. first can be called without an argument; it returns nil if the array is empty and the argument is absent.

Source for 2.0 take

```
              static VALUE
rb_ary_take(VALUE obj, VALUE n)
{
    long len = NUM2LONG(n);
    if (len < 0) {
        rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "attempt to take negative size");
    }
    return rb_ary_subseq(obj, 0, len);
}
```

Source for 2.0 first:

```
              static VALUE
rb_ary_first(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    if (argc == 0) {
        if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) == 0) return Qnil;
        return RARRAY_PTR(ary)[0];
    }
    else {
        return ary_take_first_or_last(argc, argv, ary, ARY_TAKE_FIRST);
    }
}
```

---

In terms of Rails:

1. `limit(5)` will add the scope of `limit(5)` to an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  **It can not be called on an array**, so `limit(5).limit(4)` will fail.
2. `first(5)` will add the scope of `limit(5)` to an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. **It can also be called on an array** so `.first(4).first(3)` will be the same as `.limit(4).first(3)`.
3. `take(5)` will run the query in the current scope, build all the objects and return the first 5.  **It only works on arrays**, so `Model.take(5)` will not work,  though the other two will work.

Comment: Are you sure `#limit` is not an array method? I applied it to a view on an object array `@objects` and it performed the same task as `#take` and `#first`. `#first` can take an argument (optional). Try it yourself

Comment: `take()` can be called without an argument.

Comment: @alex0112 Not in ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0 or 2.1.0

Comment: According to [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object) it can be called without an option.  According to [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-take) however, it does take an arg.  I stand corrected.

Comment: calling `#take` on a relation with also add a `limit` to the query

Answer (score 6):

The answer chosen answer seems to be outdated *(in terms of Rails)* so I would like to update some information.

1. `limit` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` will still be a `Relation`. So if you call:

   ```
   Model.limit(5).limit(4)
   ```

   will be same as:

   ```
   Model.limit(4)
   ```
2. `first` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` will make the result an `Array`. So you cannot call any scope after `first` like:

   ```
   Model.first(5).where(id: 1)
   ```

   But you can do this:

   ```
   Model.limit(5).where(id: 1)
   ```
3. `take`

   ```
   Model.take(5)
   ```

   works now. It will return an array, so you cannot call any `scope` either.

---

On an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, if you call `first` it will include `ORDER BY 'tables'.id`. Whereas with `limit` and `take` there is no `ORDER BY` included but the sorting is depended by the database sorting implementation.

Comment: In calling `limit` twice, you aren't chaining relations, you are overwriting the previous value. `Model.limit(4).limit(5)` returns 5 elements.