# getting an error with take in a query Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, take

I have a method as follows...

```
def self.get(code)
 where(code: normalize_code(code)).
 where('coupon_count > 0').
 where('expires_at > Time.now OR expires_at IS NULL').
 take
end
```

I keep getting the error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" on the "take" line. I am using rails 4.0.1 is that causing the problem or am I missing something?

EDIT Looking at the docs for 4.0.1 http://rails.documentation.codyrobbins.com/4.0.10/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take

I updated the method to

```
def self.get(code)
 where(code: normalize_code(code)).
 where('coupon_count > 0').
 where('expires_at > Time.now OR expires_at IS NULL').
 take(1)
end
```

Now I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (16722)
```

The error is on the "take" line

-UPDATE-

My error is in the where method for coupon_count. It is not in the take method. I have to figure out what it wont check the coupon_count field before accepting the coupon.

Comment: can you give the exact stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/take the docs seems to say that `take` defaults to limit the return to 1.

`Person.take # returns an object fetched by SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 1` I

However the error message suggests to me that `take` requires an argument. Check out the comments to below the answer in this question ([Arrays in Ruby: Take vs Limit vs First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555206/arrays-in-ruby-take-vs-limit-vs-first)) which basically summarises that Take cannot be called without an argument in Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0 or 2.1.0.

Comment: I am using rails 4.0.1 I went to the docs http://rails.documentation.codyrobbins.com/4.0.10/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take I updated my question

Comment: What is the Ruby version though?

Comment: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: I looked and it does look like it requires an argument http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-take

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only taking one, why not try using first instead.

Comment: tried it and got the same answer or error I should say

Comment: Well, unexpected identifier usually means there's a syntax issue or your giving it a variable that comes from a class the method isn't in. Just out of curiosity, primarily because I've never end my Rails queries with dots, what are those supposed to do?

Comment: they are chaining the methods together for 1 query

Comment: so maybe my syntax is wrong. I want it to say check the field 'coupon_code and if it is greater than or = to 1' then get that 1